# Java | boolean doesn't re-evaluate / update

Tags: java, loops, boolean, repeat, evaluation

I'm trying to make a class that let's you repeat a task a certain amount of times, or until a condition is met. Before I go on, consider the following:

```
int test = 0;
```

And my repeat class:

```
public static abstract class Repeat {

    public void loop(int c) {
        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            run();
        }
    }

    public void until(boolean c) {
        while (!c) {
            run();
        }
    }

    public abstract void run();
}
```

The issue that I have is with the `until(boolean c)` method, *not the `loop(int c)`* method. The *loop* method works just fine, as proven below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Repeat() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            test += 1;
            System.out.println(test); // so I know what test currently is
        }
        {
            loop(10);
        }
    };
}
```

That changes test by 1, 10 times. The console proves that correct:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

**Now for the issue.** If I try to use the `until()` method, it will *get laggy* if I don't terminate the launch within a few seconds, 'cause it will increment `test` infinitely.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Repeat() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            test += 1;
            System.out.println(test); // so I know what test currently is
        }
        {
            loop(10);
        }
    };
    new Repeat() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            test -= 1;
            System.out.println(test);
        }
        {
            until(test == 0);
        }
    };
}
```

**That goes on forever.** My assumption is that because the boolean that is passed in `(test == 0)` *is never updated*, so, if that is correct, can anyone tell me how to update it? And if my assumption is wrong, what causes this and how can I fix it?

**Thanks to whoever** actually reads every word I *"typed"* (mostly copy-pasted).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you pass primitives in Java through methods, it passes the value, which means that you're passing only `true` or `false`, which never updates because it's just a value. If you make something like below, though, it should work:

```
public static abstract class Repeat {
    public void loop(int c) {
        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            run();
        }
    }

    public void until() {
        while (isLooping()) {
            run();
        }
    }

    public abstract void run();
    public abstract boolean isLooping();
}
```

Returning whether or not you wish to continue looping through `isLooping()` will allow you to update the value of that boolean of yours.

Comment: I did not end up using you answer directly, but it ended up putting me on the right path to find my solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The value of `test == 0` is false when you execute `until(test == 0);`. So you're passing `false` to `until()`, and inside `until()`, the value of `!c` is thus true and never changes.

You seem to think that passing a boolean expression to a method makes the method reevaluate the expression everytime `c` is evaluated. That's not how it works. The expression is evaluated before the call to the method is made, and the **value** of that expression is passed.

Answer (score -1):

You start with test = 0 and your program only decrements test. so at the first if-clause its -1 them -2 .... its never 0

Comment: Actually no. In my code, first I have the loop block that increments 'test' to 10, THEN comes the until block that's supposed to reduce it back to zero.

Comment: tryed to make test static?